# SVG.JS GUI for drawing flowcharts?

Tags: svg.js

Has anybody wrapped SVG.js into an application for making and editing diagrams (UML) etc. ?
Preferably with connectors!?
I've been trying SVG-EDIT but it doesn't work very well. (For example it can't edit grouped texts. Some SVG cannot be imported etc.)
Thanks for your replies